# How to make Flash Player recognize my microphone

Tags: google-chrome, flash, microphone

[image]I want to be able to use the website midomi to identify songs I'm humming.
Unfortunately the microphone isn't recognized, so I went for the test mic tab.

I've explicitly allowed the site to run flash AND added the site to the exceptions that are allowed to run flash without asking.

My mic as such is working fine via Pulse.

I'm using Flash plugged into the latest chrome version. If I click setting s (global settings sends me to an Adobe manual) and head to microphone, no mic is listed.

How do I get the mic to work?